# How to identity which class object is being created in Helper class

Tags: c#

I am having a abstract class which is being inherited by 2 classes. How can I find out which class is being created in my helper class.

**Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    private IHelper helper{ get; }
    public Entity()
    {

        helper= new MyHelper(this);
    }
}
```

**MyHelper.cs**

```
public class MyHelper: IHelper
{
    private AbstractClass ABClass{get;}
    public EntityDataOperation(AbstractClass abClass)
    {
       //How can I find out which concrete type it is i.e. ClassA or ClassB
        ABClass= abClass;  
    }
}
```

**ClassA**

```
    public class ClassA:AbstractClass
    {
        public string data= "ClassA";
    }
```

**ClassB**

```
    public class ClassB:AbstractClass
    {
        public string data= "ClassB";
    }
```

Comment: Rather using GetType/typeof code, I usually include an `ItemType` property usually an enum) which identifies the Type.  `ClassA` and `ClassB` can set them in the ctor since they know what they are.

Comment: How can I Know the type in Helper Class

Comment: I don't see the type `Entity` defined? I don't see any constructor for `ClassA` or `ClassB` or `MyHelper`?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Your code still won't compile. `AbstractClass` has a constructor named `Entity`. `IHelper` isn't defined. `MyHelper` has a non-constructor `EntityDataOperation` setting a private field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection but your code and methodology is very questionable:

```
entity.GetType().Name;
```

You can also test for the subclasses

```
    if (abClass is ClassA)
        // found is ClassA
    else if (abClass is ClassB)
        // found ClassB
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question boils down to, "If I have an object, how do I get the type of that object?"

```
var typeOfTheObject = theObject.GetType();
```

The problem is that this largely defeats the purpose of strongly typed parameters.

This tells you what you need to know about the type:

```
public EntityDataOperation(AbstractClass abClass)
                             ^^^
```

That tells you what the type is. It's `AbstractClass`. If that's not what you need to know - if you don't care that it's an `AbstractClass`, then why not change the parameter to `object`?

Polymorphism literally means "multiple shapes." It means that the when you get an instance of `AbstractClass`, the actual object could be one of many shapes - many implementations of the class. But by taking a parameter of type `AbstractClass`, this method says that it doesn't care which type it is. It just interacts with the interface it knows about - the methods and properties of `AbstractClass`, without knowing or caring what the concrete implementation is.